# How to call two functions from the same endpoint. Angular, java

Tags: java, angular, spring, endpoint

Its my first time using angular and java. So Im learning from tasks. I already made a call from frontend to backend to retrieve a count number (sends number from frontend, searches the database and return the output from the query). Now I have a similar task to send the same number to backend but now when searching the database I receive 4 string returns and have to send that to frontend to output it. The problem is I don't know how to send 2 gets on the same endpoint.

ItemService

```
public PayloadResponse<Long> getCount(EntityRequest<Long> request);
```

ItemServiceImpl

```
@Override
    public PayloadResponse<Long> getCount(EntityRequest<Long> request) {
        Long itemId = request.getEntity();
        Long count = itemDAO.getCount(itemId);
        PayloadResponse<Long> response = new PayloadResponse<>(request, ResponseCode.OK, count);
        
        return response;
    }
```

ItemRestService

```
@GetMapping("/{itemId}/overview")
    public PayloadResponse<Long> getCount(@PathVariable Long itemId) {
        var request = new EntityRequest<>(itemId);
        return itemService.getCount(request);
    }
```

ItemDAO

```
public Long getCount(Long itemId) {
        String hql = "select count( distinct m.id) from ItemEntity i join MapTileResourceEntity mtr on mtr.resourceId = :itemId "
                + "and mtr.resourceType = :resourceType join MapTileEntity mt on mt.id = mtr.mapTile.id join MapEntity m on m.id = mt.map.id";
        TypedQuery<Long> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Long.class).setParameter("itemId", itemId).setParameter("resourceType",
                ObjectType.ITEM.getValue());
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "2 gets on same endpoint"?

Comment: Make a different endpoint for the new operation.  This will simplify both your Java and your Angular code.  I don't understand why you would even consider using the same endpoint for something that returns completely different data and is obviously a different operation.